# How to run a function as soon as GUI started?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I need to run a check function as soon as the tkinter GUI is available. I tried with the following code, but the Messagebox which comes up is unresponsive and I can't press the OK button.

```
import tkinter.messagebox as mbox
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk



class MQ(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.root = parent
        self.init_gui()
        if mycheck=True:
            mbox.showinfo("Title","message")

...
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    MQ(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you have in `self.init_gui()`? That might cause problems if you have another `Tk()` instance or infinite loop in there.

Comment: No, there are only a bunch of widgets placed in the grid. The application works fine without that mbox at the beginning, but i need to show an information dialog to the user an the dialog should have access to the "self" variable.

Comment: Do you have that typo in your original code? `if mycheck=True` should be `==` instad of single one.

Comment: no, it's a typo when I copied. But the problem is not there. It is in the MessageBox which remains stuck and unresponsive.

Comment: The main question is: how to run a function without any action from the user, as soon as the GUI gets displayed?

Comment: The way you do in your code is the way to do it. Put your function callings inside your init. For example, right now init_gui gets called without needing any interaction.

Comment: I have been able to reproduce the error with this simple code: https://pastebin.com/MqETCQyi
The messagbox is not closing upon pressing OK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `after_idle` to run something as soon as the GUI starts up, or you can use `after` to have it run after a brief amount of time. The two have slightly different behaviors with respect to whether the code runs before or after the root window is displayed (which might be platform dependent; I'm not sure)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

def say_hello(root, message):
    tk.messagebox.showinfo("Info", message)

root = tk.Tk()
root.after(1, say_hello, root, "Hello, world")

root.mainloop()
```